# How to filter a Meteor collection within a template

Tags: meteor, filter, routes

I have a template in which I'm populating all transfers

```
Template.listTransfers.helpers({
  transfers: function () {
    var thisId = Meteor.userId();
    return Transfers.find({userId: thisId}, {sort: {timeCreated: -1}});
  },
});
```

I also have a click event in the template that needs to filter out transfers that have invoices `return Transfers.find({userId: thisId, 'invoice' : {$exists : 1}}, {sort: {timeCreated: -1}});`

and i have the template pulling in the transfers like so

```
 {{#each transfers}}
   {{> transferItem}}
 {{/each}}
```

is there a way to do it within that statement or do i need to create a separate route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ReactiveVar on the template instance like so:

```
Template.listTransfers.created({
  // Initialize a reactive variable on the template instance
  this.showInvoices = new ReactiveVar(true);
});

Template.listTransfers.helpers({
  transfers: function () {
    var thisId = Meteor.userId();
    var showInvoices = Template.instance().showInvoices;

    if (showInvoices.get()) {
      return Transfers.find({userId: thisId}, {sort: {timeCreated: -1}});
    } else {
      return Transfers.find({userId: thisId, 'invoice' : {$exists : 1}}, {sort: {timeCreated: -1}});
    }
  },
});

Template.listTransfers.events({
  "click button.hide-invoices": function () {
    var showInvoices = Template.instance().showInvoices;

    // Toggle the showInvoices var
    showInvoices.set(! showInvoices.get());
  }
})
```